# PHP Regex: find many words between 2 parentheses

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse an "insert" MySQL database query that could looks like this:

```
insert into tablename (field1,   field2, field3) values ('te\'s ,, t', 3, "OO,\"P")
```

Assumption: the query is always 'legal' / not faulty.

The rules:

1. I want to grab **all** field names between the **first** paranthese after `tablename`

2- field names can contain `[a-z0-9_]`, it is **always** followed by either spaces or coma `[, ]`. There could be many spaces or just one or zero.

For some reasons, it doesnt work: I ask "find all words of 1-100 chars after a first parenthese, that may or not be followed by one or more coma or spaces:

```
preg_match_all( 'tablename \((\w{1,100}(?:[, ])*)+\) values/si', $matches, $allfields );
```

And I try to run a preg_match_all() in PHP and it just returns the **last** field. What am i missing?

Comment: i bet a million bananas there's a better approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: As an aside, it's a bad idea to try to parse a language as complex as SQL with a simple/naive text approach.

About your specific problem, your pattern doesn't work because you are trying to extract data from a repeated capture group. When you repeat a capture group the previous capture is always overwritten with the next and so on.

The pattern to do that is more complicated. This is a classical question: *how to extract several things (repeated things) between two substrings?*

The way to do that needs the use of the `\G` anchor that matches the position at the end of the previous result. *(note: at the begining, since there is no previous result, the `\G` anchor matches the start of the string. To avoid this case, you must use the negative lookahead `(?!\A)` to be sure that the start of the string will fail.)*

```
(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,|insert\s+into\s+tablename\s*\()\s*\K\w+
```

pattern details:

```
(?:             # non capturing group with the two possible beginings
    \G(?!\A) \s* , # contigous to the previous match, spaces, comma
  |                # OR
    insert\s+into\s+tablename\s*\( # the branch for the first result
)
\s*                        
\K    # discard all characters on the left from whole match result
\w+   # the field name
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/lF8aI7/1)

When the last field is reached, the contiguity is broken since there's only a closing parenthesis and not a comma. So `\G` will no more succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use Regex?

I would use PHPs own String functions for this.

Find the position of the opening and closing parenthese:

```
$start = strpos( $sqlQuery, "(" )
$stop = strpos( $sqlQuery, ")" )
```

Then extract the field names section with:

```
$names = substr($sqlQuery, $start, $stop - $start )
```

You could then explode the result to get an array of each individual field name:

```
$nameParts = explode($names, ",")
```

Comment: thanks. ok yes that works, it's just that i also need that script for getting the field values also, and there might be one or many ( ) inside the string values

Comment: @Joel I *think* my solution works for this case. strpos should find the *first* occurrences of "(" or ")" so it should always identify only the field names portion of the query, but there's also an offset parameter to change that. If you want the *values* portion of the query, it's a little more complicated, but not much. I'd just work backwards through the string instead of forwards.